# Cannot access webserver after ovpn client connected (on the server) to a remote network

Tags: docker, nginx, debian, cloudflare, openvpn

I have a cloud VM (debian 11) where I run some docker stuff. I have an nginx for reverese proxy, and some web application behind it.

I protect the webserver with cloudflare. I already set up the origin cert, and its works like a charm. When I reach the nginx its use the cf cert ..

BUT, I have to reach this server from my home and from the internet. I have a mikrotik router with ovpn server, and when the cloud server is connected to my network, nginx doesn't to serve web request through cloudflare. :(

When I run systemctl stop openvpn on cloud server, the webserver is reachable again. (when openvpn is connected, I can connect to nginx on private ip, but not from cloudflare.)

Do you have any idea what's happening?

The ovpn server is accessible in port 1194 on my mikrotik router.
The nginx is reachable in https://domain:443 when ovpn client is not connected. When connected is not reachable.

Comment: Please post your server.conf file.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue.

I had to comment out the redirect-gateway line from clinet.conf. Now everything works as I expect.

I can reach the server through openvpn and the server is reachable from the internet.